# oAuth "Password was not given but private key is encrypted"

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth, jira

I am writing an OAuth for Jira. But I get the error "Password was not given but the private key is encrypted". I was also trying to implement this solution with js but sadly it didn't work. Now I am trying with python.

I want to call a Jira Rest API, and for that I need the oAuth (in order to create jira tickets via code).

My Code is:

```
import requests
from oauthlib.oauth1 import SIGNATURE_RSA
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session
from jira.client import JIRA

def read(file_path):
    #""" Read a file and return it's contents. """
    with open(file_path) as f:
        return f.read()

# The Consumer Key created while setting up the "Incoming Authentication" in
# JIRA for the Application Link.
CONSUMER_KEY = ('myconsumerkey')

# The contents of the rsa.pem file generated (the private RSA key)
RSA_KEY = read('myfilelink')

# The URLs for the JIRA instance
JIRA_SERVER = 'myjiralink'
REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = JIRA_SERVER + '/plugins/servlet/oauth/request-token'
AUTHORIZE_URL = JIRA_SERVER + '/plugins/servlet/oauth/authorize'
ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = JIRA_SERVER + '/plugins/servlet/oauth/access-token'


# Step 1: Get a request token

oauth = OAuth1Session(CONSUMER_KEY, signature_type='auth_header', 
                      signature_method=SIGNATURE_RSA, rsa_key=RSA_KEY)
request_token = oauth.fetch_request_token(REQUEST_TOKEN_URL)

print("STEP 1: GET REQUEST TOKEN")
print("  oauth_token={}".format(request_token['oauth_token']))
print("  oauth_token_secret={}".format(request_token['oauth_token_secret']))
print("\n")


# Step 2: Get the end-user's authorization

print("STEP2: AUTHORIZATION")
print("  Visit to the following URL to provide authorization:")
print("  {}?oauth_token={}".format(AUTHORIZE_URL, request_token['oauth_token']))
print("\n")

while input("Press any key to continue..."):
    pass


# Step 3: Get the access token

access_token = oauth.fetch_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN_URL)

print("STEP2: GET ACCESS TOKEN")
print("  oauth_token={}".format(access_token['oauth_token']))
print("  oauth_token_secret={}".format(access_token['oauth_token_secret']))
print("\n")


# Now you can use the access tokens with the JIRA client. Hooray!

jira = JIRA(options={'server': JIRA_SERVER}, oauth={
    'access_token': access_token['oauth_token'],
    'access_token_secret': access_token['oauth_token_secret'],
    'consumer_key': CONSUMER_KEY,
    'key_cert': RSA_KEY
})

# print all of the project keys just as an exmaple
for project in jira.projects():
    print(project.key)
```

Comment: Please don't send images of code, it takes longer to go back and forth to type everything exactly the way it was. please edit your post with proper formatted code.

Comment: @ChristianKönig Sorry. I hope that now it's oke

Comment: @NaruS I edited it. I hope now it's better

Comment: much better @TeslaX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. The problem was that the private key was password protected. I removed, for now, the protection and it works.

The next step would be to authenticate with the password-private-key, but that is another question. I will mark this problem as solved.